# Obtaining velocity or acceleration vector of a point on a rigid body?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, rotational-kinematics

If I have a cube that is moving at a velocity of $v$ and spinning at an angular velocity of $\omega$, how can I determine the instantaneous velocity vector of one of the vertices of the cube?

What if the cube is accelerating? And what if it had angular acceleration, $\alpha$? Would this change the method of calculation?

Would it be possible to get an acceleration vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The total velocity will be the sum of the translational and rotational velocities. Thus
$$
\mathbf{v}_\text{net}=\mathbf{v}_\text{COM}+\mathbf{\omega}\times \mathbf r,
$$
where $\mathbf r$ is the vector from the center of mass to the vertex, and $\mathbf v_\text{COM}$ is the center of mass velocity.

Comment: Note that $\times$ is the cross product operator.

Comment: +1. $r$ is the vector distance from the CM to the vertex?

Comment: Would there be any difference if the cube was accelerating?

Comment: And would it be possible to get linear acceleration vector?

Comment: I should refer you to any classical mechanics textbook, where all this is treated. For accelerations you can try [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67053/8563).