# Apparent forces in a rotating reference system

Tags: rotational-dynamics, centrifugal-force, coriolis-effect

In Lanczos Variational Principles of Mechanics there's a subsection for apparent forces in a rotating reference system. It states that

> If the origin O of the reference system is kept fixed, the 
>   radius vectors R and R' in the absolute system S and in the 
>   moving system S' are the same: 
>   R = R'. 
>   Nevertheless, the velocities and accelerations measured in both 
>   systems differ from each other because of the fact that rates of 
>   change observed in the two systems are different. If a certain 
>   vector B is constant in S' it rotates with the system and thus, if 
>   observed in S, undergoes in the time dt an infinitesimal change 
>   $$dB = (\Omega \times B) dt$$ Therefore $$\frac{dB}{dt} = (\Omega \times B)$$
>   and $$\frac{d'B}{dt}=0 $$ where $\frac{d'}{dt}$ refers to the operation of observing the rate of change of a quantity in the moving system S'. If the vector B is not constant in S', so that $\frac{d'B}{dt}\ne0$, then we find, by making use of the principle of infinitesimal processes, that 
>   $$\frac{dB}{dt}=\frac{d'B}{dt}+\Omega \times B$$ applying this to the radius vector $R=R'$ we get
>   $$\frac{dR}{dt}=\frac{d'R'}{dt}+\Omega \times R'$$ which gives 
>   $$v = v' + \Omega \times R'$$
>   Differentiating then gives 
>   $$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dv'}{dt} + \dot\Omega \times R' + \Omega \times \frac{dR'}{dt}$$

It is stated that this can be expressed in terms of quantities only belonging to S' as
$$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{d'v'}{dt} + 2\Omega \times v' + \Omega \times (\Omega \times R') + \Omega \times R'$$ by using
$$\frac{dB}{dt}=\frac{d'B}{dt}+\Omega \times B$$

But I'm failing to see which quantity doesn't belong to S' and how they are getting the final equation. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Related : [*Velocity in a turning reference frame*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67053/velocity-in-a-turning-reference-frame/252265#252265).

Comment: Any term which contains $\frac{d\,\,}{dt}$ needs to be transformed into terms containing $\frac{d’\,}{dt}$