# Time derivative in rotating frame

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, time, differentiation, rigid-body-dynamics

In Goldstein (2ed) sec 4.9 - Rate of change of a vector, why does he say that the instantaneous angular velocity **$\omega$** is not a derivative of any vector?

> $$ (d\textbf{G})_{space} = (d\textbf{G})_{body} + d\pmb\Omega \times \textbf{G} $$
>   The time *rate of change* of the vector $\textbf{G}$ as seen by the two observers is then obtained by dividing the terms by the differential time element $dt$ under consideration;
>   $$ \bigg ( \frac{d\textbf{G}} {dt} \bigg)_{space} = \bigg ( \frac{d\textbf{G}} {dt} \bigg)_{body} + \pmb\omega \times \textbf{G} $$
>   Here $\pmb\omega$ is the instantaneous *angular velocity* of the body defined by the relation*
>   $$\pmb\omega dt = d\pmb\Omega $$
>   *As  $\pmb\omega$ is not the derivative of any vector, it is sometimes described as a *nonholonomic* vector, in analogy to the nonintegrable differential constraints.

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/419773/226902