# Velocity in rotating frame projected onto axis in inertial frame

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, rotational-kinematics, rotation

I want to look at the projection of the velocity of a particle in the rotating frame onto an axis in the inertial frame as a function of time. For example, I am calculating

\begin{equation}
\frac{d\boldsymbol{r}}{dt}=\frac{d\boldsymbol{r}'}{dt}+\boldsymbol{\Omega}\times\boldsymbol{r}'
\end{equation}

Where $\boldsymbol{r}$ is the position vector of the particle, the un-primed is the inertial frame and the prime the rotating. $\Omega$ is the angular velocity of the rotating frame with respect to the inertial, and can also be a function of time. Then I would like to look at the $z$-axis component of $\frac{d\boldsymbol{r}}{dt}$ which is  $\frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{d\boldsymbol{r}}{dt}\bullet\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}$. Then from above I have

\begin{equation}
\frac{dz}{dt}=\left(\frac{d\boldsymbol{r}'}{dt}+\boldsymbol{\Omega}\times\boldsymbol{r}'\right)\bullet\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}
\end{equation}

Which now means I need to look at the dot products of $\hat{\boldsymbol{i}}'\bullet\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}\quad, \hat{\boldsymbol{j}}'\bullet\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}\quad$  and  $ \hat{\boldsymbol{k}}'\bullet\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}$. I am confused about how to proceed with doing this?

Comment: Related : [Velocity in a turning reference frame](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67053/velocity-in-a-turning-reference-frame/252265#252265)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define the orientation of the rotating frame you need a 3×3 orthonormal rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$. This will give you the local to the inertial frame transformation of vectors using a matrix-vector product.

$$ \mathbf{c} = \mathbf{R}\, \mathbf{c}' $$

Now the columns of $\mathbf{R}$ are exactly the dot product you described, or the components of the local coordinates expressed in the inertial frame

$$ \mathbf{R} = \left[ \begin{array}{c|c|c}
  \boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}}' & \boldsymbol{\hat{\jmath}}' & \boldsymbol{\hat{k}}' \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{c|c|c}
  \boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}}' \cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}} & \boldsymbol{\hat{\jmath}}' \cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}} & \boldsymbol{\hat{k}}'\cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}} \\  \boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}}' \cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{\jmath}} & \boldsymbol{\hat{\jmath}}' \cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{\jmath}} & \boldsymbol{\hat{k}}'\cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{\jmath}} \\
 \boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}}' \cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{k}} & \boldsymbol{\hat{\jmath}}' \cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{k}} & \boldsymbol{\hat{k}}'\cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{k}} \end{array}  \right] = \left[ \matrix{ \hat{\imath}_x' & \hat{\jmath}_x' & \hat{k}_x' \\ \hat{\imath}_y' & \hat{\jmath}_y' & \hat{k}_y'  \\ \hat{\imath}_z' & \hat{\jmath}_z' & \hat{k}_z' } \right] $$

Now specifically, the kinematics of a rotating frame are derived from the transformation of coordinates:

$$ \mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}_0 + \mathbf{R}\, \mathbf{r}' $$

<sub>Here $\mathbf{r}_0$ is the origin of the rotating frame in inertial coordinates, $\mathbf{R}$ the 3×3 orientation matrix, $\mathbf{r}'$ the position vector in the rotating frame, and $\mathbf{r}$ the position vector in the inertial frame.</sub>

Take the derivative of the above to get

$$ \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}_0 + \boldsymbol{\Omega} \times \mathbf{R}\, \mathbf{r}' + \mathbf{R}\, \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}'}{\partial t}  $$

<sub>This hinges on the property that the rotation matrix represents 3 unit length vectors and hence $\dot{\mathbf{R}} = \boldsymbol{\Omega} \times \mathbf{R}$.</sub>

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Is your primed the local or inertial frame? I'm also still unsure how to use this information to obtain the velocity of $\dot{z}$(the z-component of velocity in the inertial frame). Do I need to calculate the components of $\boldsymbol{R}$?

Comment: The _z_-direction of velocity is the 3rd component of $\mathbf{v}$. Yes, you need to define $\mathbf{R}$ based on axis-angle, euler-angles or quaternions. The primed unit vectors $\mathbf{\hat{\imath}}'$ etc contain the components of the rotating coordinate system expressed in the inertial system.

Comment: Ah, so i've been calculating the velocity in the inertial frame by just plugging in $\boldsymbol{r}'$ without the $\boldsymbol{R}$ in yours, which I can now see is wrong? What would you say is the easiest way to go about obtaining $\boldsymbol{R}$ axis-angle, euler-angles or quaternions?  I'd like to keep $\boldsymbol{\Omega}$ time dependent in general does this change $\boldsymbol{v}$ at all?

Comment: If $\mathbf{\Omega}(t)$ is a function of time, then $\mathbf{v}$ isn't affected, but $\dot{\mathbf{v}}$ is. If you have a single fixed rotation axis, then use the axis angle method. If you have a free body, then euler-angles is a good start. It is best to work with a common inertial reference frame early on in order to avoid confusions. That is why I am starting with inertial position $\mathbf{r}$ first and deriving everything from there using time derivatives.

Comment: The rotation axis $\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}$ where $\boldsymbol{\Omega}=\Omega\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}$ is not fixed, it is a function of time so I'm looking at Euler angles. It doesn't seem easy to obtain these angles from a time dependent rotation axis, am I over complicating this problem or is it just not that trivial?

Comment: You need to provide more details on how the axis of rotation changes. Is it a simple motion (like precession)? The kinematics of the parts derive the modeling techniques. Use existing physical joints or connections.

Comment: The rotating frame oscillates about the inertial frame axes with a form $\Omega_x(t)=\mu_x\omega_x\cos(\omega_xt)$ where $\mu_x$ is the amplitude of rocking about the x-axis and $\omega_x$ the frequency of rocking, and similar rocking for the y-axis and z-axis. The only joint I have assumed is that the two frames are joined at the origin.

Comment: Use axis-angle. $\hat{\mathbf{n}} = \pmatrix{\mu_x \\ \mu_y \\ \mu_z }$ and $ \theta = \sin(\omega t) $. But you need all the components of the rotation to be "in-phase" with $\boldsymbol{\Omega} = \hat{\mathbf{n}} \omega \cos( \omega t)$. Otherwise you are not representign a real physical system. You cannot have three independent time fuctions for the rotation vector and integrate them to get the rotation matrix. At least not analytically. You can numerically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82802/discussion-between-jamie1989-and-ja72).