# Derivative of rotation matrix in a form skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: group-theory, differentiation, rotation, lie-algebra

I am working on an application of CV, in which a way to calculate the derivative of rotation matrix is involved.

$$R$$ is the rotation matrix and $$R \in SO(3)$$
Also, $R$ is changing with $t$ giving $R(t)$.

$R(t)R(t)^\mathrm{T} = I$ is known. We calculate the derivative of $R(t)R(t)^\mathrm{T} $ which gives us a skew symmetric matrix $\dot{R}(t)R(t)^\mathrm{T} = -R(t)\dot{R}{}^\mathrm{T}(t) =: \phi(t)$, where
$$\phi (t) = \left[ \begin{matrix}
0 & -\phi_3  & \phi_2 \\
\phi_3 & 0 & -\phi_1\\
-\phi_2 & \phi_1 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right].
$$

The derivative of $R(t)$ is then given by
$$
\dot{R}(t) = \phi (t)  R(t).$$

To derive the Lie algebra, later, it gives the 1st order expansion of $R(t)$
$$ R(t) \approx R(t_0) + \dot{R}(t_0)\ (t-t_0) = I + t\ \phi (t_0) ,$$
where $t_0 = 0$ and $R(t_0) = I$.
By given an assumption that $\phi (t_0) = \phi_0$ around $t_0$, it gets
$$
\dot{R}(t) = \phi (t_0) R(t) = \phi_0 R(t).$$
This is the one I cannot get, i.e. the last equation is my question.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Related : [Velocity in a turning reference frame](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67053/velocity-in-a-turning-reference-frame/252265#252265).

Comment: with Euler-Rodrigues-Formel is the rotation matrix $R=\exp \left( \left[ \overrightarrow{\varphi }\right] _{x}\right) $ where $\vec \varphi$ is the rotation axis and $\vec\varphi\cdot\vec\varphi=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\phi$ can be thought of as the tangent vector $\text{d}/\text{d}t$ of $R(t)$. For any $R(t)$, we can use the exponential map to obtain
$$R(t_0 + t) = R(t_0) + t\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} R(t_0) + \frac{1}{2!}\left(t \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\right)^2 R(t_0) + \frac{1}{3!}\left(t \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\right)^3 R(t_0) + \ldots \\ = \sum^\infty_{n = 0} \frac{1}{n!} \left(t \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\right)^n = e^{t \phi } R |_{t_0}$$

By definition $R(t_0 = 0) = I$, we have
$$R(t) = e^{t\phi}$$

and we can differentiate the matrix exponential to obtain
$$\dot{R}(t) = \phi e^{t\phi} = \phi_0 R(t)$$

Comment: Thanks, Vincent. I forget this full expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Use your $t_0 = 0$  so $R(0) = I$,
$$\dot{R}(t)R(t)^\mathrm{T}   =: \phi(t)= \phi(0)+ O(t)\leadsto \\
\dot{R}(t)= (\phi_0+ O(t) ) R(t)= (\phi_0+ O(t) )( I+ O(t))= \phi_0+ O(t)  .
$$
The order *t* terms vanish at 0, so $\dot{R}(0)=\phi_0$, antisymmetric, alright.

Comment: Thanks as well, Cosmas.

Comment: Cosmas, I have a little more to ask. It is simply about the symbol in my question you edited.  Is that OK to use $$\phi(t) = \left[ \begin{matrix} x & x & x \\  x & x & x \\ x & x& x \end{matrix} \right]$$ instead of $\phi(t)^{\wedge}$ representing a skew symmetric matrix of vector $\phi(t)$. I want them in my assignment report.

Comment: Cosmas, I have a little more to ask. It is simply about the symbol in my question you edited.  Is that OK to use $$\phi(t) = \left [

Comment: No, the object you *defined* is manifestly antisymmetric, as you demonstrate.