# Vector form of centrepetal force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors, centripetal-force

We know the centripetal force $F_c$ had magnitude $m\omega^2r$. But let's try to write it in vector form.

First of all,since it is directed along the radius,the unit vector in radial direction in this case is $-\hat{\boldsymbol{r}}$. And since the magnitude is $m\omega^2r$,we finally get $$\vec{\mathrm{F_c}}=-\mathrm{m}\mathrm{\omega}^2\mathrm{r}\hat{\boldsymbol{r}}=-\mathrm{m}\frac{v^2}{r^2}\vec{\mathrm{r}}.$$

But this is not how it us done in the books. According to them,$$\vec{\mathrm{F_c}}=-\mathrm{m}\frac{v^2}{r^3}\vec{\mathrm{r}}.$$

I don't understand how they got it,the one i did seems to be completely fine to me. Could anyone tell me the mistake i made?

Comment: Can you give a source of where you found this formula?

Comment: I doubt the fact that you found it in "books". Maybe in one book there is a typo.

Comment: Is it really a book or just some PDF notes? I, remember, few months ago I found a person written it on facebook.

Comment: Related : [Velocity in a turning reference frame](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67053/velocity-in-a-turning-reference-frame).\begin{equation}  \mathbf{A}=\mathbf{{A}_{0}}+\overset{_{^{\bullet}}}{\boldsymbol{\Omega}}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{r}+\underset{\text{Centripetal}}{\underbrace{\boldsymbol{\Omega}\boldsymbol{\times}\left(\boldsymbol{\Omega}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{r}\right)}}+\underset{\text{-Coriolis}}{\underbrace{2\:\left(\boldsymbol{\Omega}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{u}\:\right)}}+\mathbf{a} 
\tag{23}  
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

In times of doubt it is nice to have a simple example on which we can rely. Start with uniform circular motion:
\begin{align}
\vec r&=r(\cos(\omega t),\sin(\omega t))\\
\vec v&=r\omega(-\sin(\omega t),\cos(\omega t))\\
\vec a&=-r\omega^2(\cos(\omega t),\sin(\omega t))
\end{align}
From the second formula we can derive $v=r\omega\implies\omega=\frac{v}r$. We can write the last formula as $\vec a=-\omega^2\vec r$. Combining these two gives
\begin{align}
\vec a&=-\frac{v^2}{r^2}\vec r\\
\vec F_C&=-\frac{mv^2}{r^2}\vec r
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The formula given in the book is obviously wrong, and the dimensions it-self are incorrect.  You are not wrong, the book is.

Answer (score 0):

The vector form is $$ \vec{F} = m \left( \vec{\omega} \times (\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}) \right) \tag{1}$$

where $m$ is the mass of the object, $\vec{r}$ is the position of the center of mass relative to the axis of rotation, and $\vec{\omega}$ is rotational (orbital) velocity of the body.

This is derived from the velocity of the center of mass when rotating about a fixed axis

$$ \vec{v} = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r} \tag{2}$$

where $\times$ is the vector cross product. In a rotating frame, the cross product provides the changes in a vector due to the rotation of the local directions.

Then the change in velocity (acceleration vector) which is derived from the time derivative of velocity is

$$ \vec{a} = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{v} = \vec{\omega} \times ( \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}) \tag{3}$$

Finally, the force required to provide this acceleration is $\vec{F} = m \vec{a}$ and hence (1).

Answer (score -1):

Here, $\hat{\mathbf{r}}$ is a unit vector in radial direction whereas, $\vec{\mathbf{r}}$ is a position vector.

Also, $\vec{\mathbf{r}} = |\vec{\mathbf{r}}|\hat{\mathbf{r}}$.

This implies, $\vec{F} = -\frac{mv^2}{r^3}\vec{\mathbf{r}}  = -\frac{mv^2}{r^3}|\vec{\mathbf{r}}|\hat{\mathbf{r}} = -\frac{mv^2}{r^2}\hat{\mathbf{r}} $.

The mistake you did is change $\hat{\mathbf{r}}$ to $\vec{\mathbf{r}}$ in your first equation.

Comment: This is wrong, check your dimensions. $\frac{mv^2}{r^2}$ has dimensions of $$\frac{\text{M}\times\text{L}^2}{\text{T}^2 \times \text{L}^2} = \frac{\text{M}}{\text{T}^2}$$ but force is $\frac{\text{M}\times{\text{L}}}{\text{T}^2}$