# Time derivatives in a rotating frame of reference

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems

I am watching a youtube video regarding time derivatives in a rotating reference frame. The stationary reference frame is S and the rotating one is S'.

Unfortunately I don't understand why the red underlined formula is valid.  Is it because there is no external force acting?

[image]

Because with two reference systems, where one is stationary and the other moves with a constant velocity, it is the case, if a force acts on a test particle, that the force is the same in both reference systems, but not the measured velocity.

Comment: It's only kinematics here, no dynamics, no force. If you have a vector, you can write using different vector bases, as it's done there in the rotating frame. They're only writing the vector $\vec{A}$ as the linear combination of the vectors of the bases $\{\hat{i}', \hat{j}', \hat{k}' \}$

Comment: Related : [Velocity in a turning reference frame](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67053/velocity-in-a-turning-reference-frame).

Comment: The formula is just the expansion of $\vec{A}$ in the S' frame. No mechanics involved here (no forces etc). The real meat of the derivation comes later.

Answer (score 0):

The vector $\vec{A}$ has different components depending on which direction vectors you want to use.

In the example they declare the components of $\vec{A}$ in terms of the frame *S*' as $$\vec{A} =\pmatrix{A_x' \\ A_y' \\ A_z'}$$

such that $$\vec{A} = A_x' \hat{i}' +A_y' \hat{j}' + A_z' \hat{k}' \tag{1}$$

This is done because $\vec{A}$ is a vector defined in S' and riding along the moving frame. But the components are measured from S. This is a bit confusing with this nomenclature.

Now let's see how the components vary with time. We call this

$$\left. \frac{{\rm d}\vec{A}}{{\rm d}t} \right|_S \tag{2}$$

because we are sitting on S measuring the components of $\vec{A}$

Now the first line just substitutes (1) into (2).

$$\left. \frac{{\rm d}\vec{A}}{{\rm d}t} \right|_S = \left. \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} \right|_S \left( A_x' \hat{i}' +A_y' \hat{j}' + A_z' \hat{k}' \right)  \tag{3}$$